# Get vectors between two vectors 3D

Tags: math, vector, 3d

I need a formula to get points position between 2 3D vectors.
e.g
I have 2 3D vectors v1 = (2,3,4) and v2 = (4,3,10). To get avarage point between these two vector I do v3 = (v1+v2)/2. That will be (3,3,7) But I need the formula to get any number of points(v3, v4, v5 etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formula of linear intepolation

```
v3 = v1 * (1 - t)  + v2 * t
```

where parameter t varies in range 0..1

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for,.